# Hibernate and Resin working together

Tags: hibernate, web.xml, persistence.xml, resin

I am new to resin and am trying to get Hibernate to work with it.  I am running into some problems with the JNDI lookup of the data source.  I keep getting "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException".  I have a special case where I need to dynamically create an EntityManager with passing in the url property. so when I set up my web.xml it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin">
    <database jndi-name="jdbc/evolution">
        <driver>
            <type>org.postgresql.Driver</type>
        </driver>
    </database>

    <ejb-server data-source="jdbc/evolution"/>
</web-app>
```

and my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="evolution">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!--<provider>com.caucho.amber.manager.AmberPersistenceProvider</provider>-->
        <!--<jta-data-source>jdbc/evolution</jta-data-source>-->
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/evolution</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

here is the code I am using to get the Entity manager:

```
public class DatabaseConnectionFactory {
    public static EntityManager createManager(String databaseName) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf;
        Map properties = new HashMap();

        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + databaseName);
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "postgres");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");


        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("evolution", properties);
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

when it tries to create the entity manager I get a

*javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/env/jdbc/evolution*

I have also tried putting in jdbc/evolution in the jta-data-source tag in the persistence.xml.  The weird thing is when I first hit a break point in a servlet and lookup the "java:comp/env/jdbc/evolution" object myself through InitialContext it finds it, but once it gets into the hibernate code it can't. Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

After getting enough sleep last night I realized that I was trying to mix 2 technologies and that I did not need the jta-data-source at all.  Since I was only needing the persistence.xml to create me a persistence-unit and then supply the rest of the connection properties in code.  I removed the jta-data-source and all was happy after that. So my persistence.xml now looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="evolution">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

now I get a result back from teh Entity Manager.  Yipee!